# Loading a CSV File into Oracle Table

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle ApEx and I was wondering on what is the best way to upload a single column csv file into an Oracle table, to be used within ApEx?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: Import CSV file using SQLPLUS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198863/oracle-import-csv-file-using-sqlplus)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues as you. 
You probably already found the solution but I follow the method in this link
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=545565
and it works for me. They used external tables. The maximum number of columns is 50.

Other option is http://avdeo.com/2008/05/21/uploading-excel-sheet-using-oracle-application-express-apex/
However, I found that if your CSV contains some special character, it does not run properly.

Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

To load a CSV file using SQLLOADER you will need to do the following:

(a) The CSV file
(b) SQLLOADER Control file (also known as CTL file)
(c) SQLLOADER command to use the CTL file in (b) to load the CSV file in (a).

CSV file, you already have that.  For this example, the file name is temp.csv contains two columns

```
A,100
B,200
C,300
D,400
```

Now, you need to create a control to describe the file and which table to load it to, and how to load it.  For this example, the control file name called temp.ctl and the table you want to load into is TEMP_TABLE that contains two columns, COLUMN_1 is VARCHAR2(2), COLUMN_2 is NUMBER.  The temp.ctl looks like the below

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TEMP_TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  COLUMN_1 CHAR,
  COLUMN_2 Integer EXTERNAL
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed for your help but do not want to use SQL*Loader - pls see my comment above.

Comment: @ Mohamed i would definately need your help in SQL*Loader to load csv file into oracle db

Comment: FYR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198863/oracle-import-csv-file-using-sqlplus

Answer (score 0):

Big files:

- sqlloader
- external tables

Small files:

- own parsing

Comment: Thanks but not looking at using SQL*Loader as this will be done by an end user so would like to allow them to choose the file from Oracle ApEx, to upload from their PC and then parse and then load into a table. What is the best way to parse a single column csv into oracle table? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with awk.

Here is example on how to populate table from .csv data.

```
SQL> create table MY_TABLE(a varchar2(100), b varchar2(100));

[oracle@myora ~]$ tail Some_Input_CSV_file
Some Data A 1,Some Data B 1
Some Data A 2,Some Data B 2
Some Data A 3,Some Data B 3
Some Data A 4,Some Data B 4
Some Data A 5,Some Data B 5
Some Data A 6,Some Data B 6
Some Data A 7,Some Data B 7
Some Data A 8,Some Data B 8
Some Data A 9,Some Data B 9
Some Data A 10,Some Data B 10
[oracle@myora ~]$

[oracle@myora ~]$ cat Some_Input_CSV_file | awk -F, ‘ { printf(“insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(\x27%s\x27), trim(\x27%s\x27));\n”, $1, $2); } ‘ > RunMe.sql

[oracle@myora ~]$ tail RunMe.sql
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 1′), trim(‘Some Data B 1′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 2′), trim(‘Some Data B 2′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 3′), trim(‘Some Data B 3′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 4′), trim(‘Some Data B 4′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 5′), trim(‘Some Data B 5′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 6′), trim(‘Some Data B 6′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 7′), trim(‘Some Data B 7′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 8′), trim(‘Some Data B 8′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 9′), trim(‘Some Data B 9′));
insert into MY_TABLE values(trim(‘Some Data A 10′), trim(‘Some Data B 10′));
[oracle@myora ~]$

[oracle@myora ~]$ sqlplus myuser/mypwd@myinst

SQL> @RunMe.sql

…

1 row created.

1 row created.

1 row created.

1 row created.

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> exit
```