# Loading data from a web-hosted CSV into Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I don't have time to write a perl or anything like that nor do I have admin access to the back end, so how can I get data from a file on the intranet (http://) and parse it to create a table? Maybe somehow via PL/SQL? Keep in mind I don't have much admin access.

Comment: Is this a one-time load?  An ongoing process?  Are you trying to completely automate it or is a process that involves human intervention acceptable?

Comment: I want it to be automated. But from what I understand I can use PL/SQL scheduler to do that.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198863/oracle-import-csv-file-using-sqlplus

Comment: @alfasin...not a duplicate...different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to be completely automated

- You can use the [UTL_HTTP package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_http.htm) to retrieve the data from the HTTP server
- You can either parse the CSV response yourself using INSTR and SUBSTR or you can use the UTL_FILE package to write the data to a file on the database server file system and then create an external table that parses the CSV file you just created.
- You can then insert the parsed data into a table you've already created (I'm assuming that the CSV data is in the same format each time).
- You can use the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` or `DBMS_JOB` package to schedule the job

The Oracle database account you're using will need to be granted access to all of these packages.

Answer (score 0):

You may download the file into your host machine and then use SQL*Loader to populate a table.

Other ways there are some wizards that may be easier than SQL*Loader, if you are using IDEs like PLSQLDeveloper(Tools->Text Importer) or SQLDeveloper(right click on Tables-> Import Data).

Answer (score 0):

Create an external table that references your CSV file. That means you can run select statements on the file from within Oracle.