# What is the easiest way to 'dump' a temp-table into SQL format

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Version: 10.2b

So lets say I have a table dogs in progress:

```
table: dogs 
fields: name, age, breed
```

I want to load them into oracle database using the standard load utility. But the table in oracle looks like this

```
table: dog
fields: name, age, date_last_updated
```

so if i make a temp-table matching this, is there a way to 'dump' the temp table into sql? (so that i can load it into oracle)

If not, that is a fine answer too.

Thanks for any help!!

EDIT:
By 'sql dump' I mean:

```
INSERT INTO dog
VALUES (Max, 5, Feb 18, 2013)
```

is there any way to get the table in this format other then exporting the words "INSERT INTO" into my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Database Management Tool with ODBC Support ([DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) for example) you can
connect to progress Databases and export Tables and Views to SQL Inserts.

Comment: yes, I though about this but the table I need to load into is different then my progress table. That's why I though maybe exporting a temp-table.

Comment: I think it should be possible to export not only tables but also query results or views. That way you could change the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification.

From the 4GL the "natural" way to dump a table (either a real table or a temp-table) would be to use the EXPORT statement to create a text file.  Like so:

```
/* export the dog record as-is
 */

output to "dog.d".
for each dog no-lock:
  export dog.
end.
output close.
```

or:

```
/* export modified dog records
 */

output to "dog.d".
for each dog no-lock:
  export dog.name dog.age now.
end.
output close.
```

This [Oracle: Import CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198863/oracle-import-csv-file-using-sqlplus) suggests that importing CSV files into Oracle is possible so you could modify the code above like so to create a comma separated file rather than using Progress' default space delimiter:

```
/* export modified dog records to a CSV file
 */

output to "dog.csv".
for each dog no-lock:
  export delimiter "," dog.name dog.age now.
end.
output close.
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, something like this would work. You can also replace the "TT" references with the actual table name.

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE("sqldump").

FOR EACH tt-dogs:

  PUT UNFORMATTED
     "INSERT INTO dog VALUES (" tt-dogs.dog-name tt-dogs.age TODAY ")" SKIP.

END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.
```