# Dynamic insert sql statements generation

Tags: python, sql, insert

I want to generate dynamic insert statements using python script. I will be using the data from a csv file to get the inserts:
 so far this is what I am able to accomplish via google:

```
import csv
openFile = open('test.csv', 'r')
csvFile = csv.reader(openFile)
header = next(csvFile)
headers = map((lambda x: '`'+x+'`'), header)
insert = 'INSERT INTO Table (' + ", ".join(headers) + ") VALUES "
for row in csvFile:
    values = map((lambda x: '"'+x+'"'), row)
    print (insert +"("+ ", ".join(values) +");" )
openFile.close()
```

the insert statements should have single quotes only on strings and not on numbers.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? PostgreSQL and MySQL both have specialised syntax for loading CSV data. I'm sure others do as well.

Comment: I am using oracle for now.I do not want to fire the insert the statements directly on the database. I want to just save the output in a .sql file

Comment: You might find this useful -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198863/oracle-import-csv-file

Comment: I was looking more of a program where I can generate statements like delete and inserts