# Insert multiple CSV files into one oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking to important around 100 csv files with the same data throughout all of them. I am using oracle SQL developer

Comment: Please add details of what you have tried and at what point you're encountering a problem.

Comment: Just to make sure: your database is MS SQL Server, and the tool you use is Oracle SQL Developer. It that correct?

Comment: I have tried to search up methods to do this and can't seem to find anything to do it in one bulk import. any tips?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198863/oracle-import-csv-file

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes i believe so

Comment: So, this didn't work?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076309/import-multiple-csv-files-to-sql-server-from-a-folder  (I think you need to do a bit more research and tell us what exactly you're attempting and what exactly isn't working...you are not the first person to attempt this task and there is a lot out there in terms of tutorials, previous questions with answers, etc)

Comment: this is not the type SQL i am using so it does not apply. I am not very caught up with the technologies apologies

Comment: are they all the same definition, going to the same table? if so, then you want external tables, or sqlldr

Comment: You need to fix the tags on your question if it's not MS Sql Server.

Answer (score 2):

Is this SQL Server or Oracle?  Either way, if I were you, I would merge all 100 files into one single file, and load that into any database you are working with.  Python will easily do the merge task for you.  Then, load the consolidated file into your DB.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

#os.chdir("C:\\your_path\\")
results = pd.DataFrame([])
filelist = glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\test\\*.csv")
#dfList=[]
for filename in filelist:
    print(filename)  
    namedf = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=0, index_col=0)
    results = results.append(namedf)

results.to_csv('C:\\your_path\\CombinedFile.csv')
```