# How Can I Insert Data Into Oracle Table Through Object?

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11g, user-defined-types

types,tables and nested table code in below.

```
create type virus_spread_details_t as object(
sDate date,
deadCount int,
recoveredCount int,
infectedCount int
)
/
```

```
create type virus_spread_details_tbl as table of virus_spread_details_t
```

```
create type countries_t as object(
ProvinceOrState varchar2(30),
CountryOrRegion varchar2(50),
Latitude Number(10,6),
Longtude Number(10,6),
virusSpread virus_spread_details_tbl
)
/
```

```
create table VirusSpreadcountries of countries_t(
primary key(ProvinceOrState, CountryOrRegion)
CountryOrRegion varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
) nested table virusSpread store as virus_nested_table;
```

i have csv file it was merged using phython.

it contains 8 columns.

```
Province/State
Country/Region
Latitude
Longtude
Date
ConfirmedPatients
DeathPatients
RecoveredPatients
```

i want to import this CSV file into oracle **sqlplus**.how can I import this CSV through the object.

Comment: Loading a CSV into a database is [one issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6198863/146325). Working with Oracle ORDBMS capabilities is [a completely orthogonal issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+user-defined-type+insert).